# Array.sort for Binary Search

Tags: sorting, arraylist, binary-search

I am trying to sort an array for a binary search method but I am not sure which approach to take to sort the array. I have tried Arrays.sort and Collections but they return exceptions both times I try to run the program. Looking for some of the elements in the array does return values but for other values such as an input of (3 5) in the array, where it returns a value of 5 but I want a value of 7 once it is sorted. I don't know which approach to take or if I'm on the right path so would I appreciate any help!

```
 /**
 * Binary search to fix data sets issues
 */
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class BinarySearch {
  /** Use binary search to find the key in the list */
  public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length - 1;

    while (high >= low) {
      int mid = (low + high) / 2;
      if (key < list[mid])
        high = mid - 1;
      else if (key == list[mid])
        return mid;
      else
        low = mid + 1;
    }

    return -low - 1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

     int set = in.nextInt();
     int key = in.nextInt();

     int[][] datasets = { {},
                          {1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89},
                          {-81, -72, -63, -54, -45, -36, -27, -18, -9, 0},
                          {21, 34, 72, -63, 8, 5, -13, -27, -18, 1, 0, 2}
                        };
     //Arrays.sort(datasets);
 //Collections.sort(datasets);
     System.out.println("Searching for key " + key + 
                        " in data set " + set +
                        " returned " + binarySearch(datasets[set], key));

  }
}
```

Comment: What errors you get?

Comment: What are you doing here exactly??